# Linked List print issue structure

Tags: c

I developed a linked list but when I pass "head" as a parameter to print a Linked List, program crashes or returns a garbage memory data. If, I pass "middle" as a parameter list works fine as intended and returns the data stored in the middle and the last structure node. Using Visual Studio 2017 professional edition for development on Windows 10 pro workstation.

I've pasted the complete code for your feedback. thanks!

```
  // A single linked list 
  #include<stdio.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void printList(struct Node* n);  // function prototype

int main()
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *middle;
    struct Node *last;

    // allocate 3 nodes in the heap
    head = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    middle = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    last = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if (head != NULL) {
        head->data = 11;
        head->data = middle;
    }
    middle->data = 22;
    middle->next = last;
    last->data = 12;
    last->next = NULL;

    printList(head);

    _getch();

    return 0;
}

void printList(struct Node* n)
{
    while (n != NULL) 
    {
        printf(" %d\n", n->data);
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed C++ tag; this is all C code.

Comment: Please take a look at the gcc warning: 'head->data = middle' (line 26) should be 'head->next = middle'.

Comment: Good practice is to get clean gcc build. Also, consider replacing malloc with calloc - it will eliminate random data in allocated blocks, in case the code does not initialize all required fields.

Comment: Thank guys, problem solved by replacing head->data = middle TO head->next = middle;

Comment: @mzahid: there is a proper answer with that information. Please up-vote and select that answer as the good answer, according to the etiquette rules of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Problem because of this line `head->data = middle;`. Have to be `head->next = middle;`